# How To Set Up Hyper-V Nested Virtualization in the Linux (include how to use the same IP and different port)

Tags: linux, ip, vmware-server

Question list as below:

> 1. How to create nested VM?
> 2. How to setup VM Hardware in the dashboard?
> 3. How to use the same IP address and the different port number

PS: I still have been trying some ways that are okay to deal with my problem and I will show it on the answer content. However, some of the steps aren't okay.

Answer (score 0):

Stpe1:To Open BIOS Hyper-V on the main hardware
[Reference](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2015/09/08/step-by-step-enabling-hyper-v-for-use-on-windows-10/)
1. Notebook:please open a Notebook BIOS to setup the Hyper-V
2.  VMware station:please use the VM dashboard to open the virtualize BIOS to setup the Hyper-V

Step2: To setup the VM Hardware
[image]
[image]